# Java > int to double(Scanner>System.out)

Tags: java, int, double

It is my first question) Hope someone can help:

I'm trying write next programm:
So i have 1 input and max 2 output
First of all i am checking if input is (int!) 
if TRUE i print out message that "YES IT IS INTEGER" and show "saved number in varaible int",

but if i put double, i want to print out message =(" NO it is not INT)  +
and show it in double format!

Everything is ok while i put int but when i put double it is not correct.

```
public class Scan {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int check;
            System.out.println("Your number? ");

        if(sc.hasNextInt()){
        check=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("OKEI "+check+ " IT IS INTEGER! ");}
        else if(sc.hasNextDouble()){
        check=sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Nooo " + check + " NO it is not INT");
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: What means `when i put double it is not correct`

Comment: @Jens He likely means that he entered a `double`, but it behaves like an integer (because the variable into which he is storing that `double` input _is_ an integer).

Comment: Note that the Double format depends on the Locale use, so depending on the System configuration, a Double could be `1.25` or `1,25`

Answer (score 2):

One solution is having `check` as a `double` instead, and change the check to:

```
if (check == Math.floor(check))
```

In your solution, you're trying to assign a `double` to an `int`. Since it doesn't fit, it'll loose precision and be truncated.

Final solution should look like:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
check = sc.nextDouble();
if (check == Math.floor(check)) {
    // an "int"
} else {
    // not integer
}
```

Comment: I would have use `if(check  - (int) check  == 0)` but this would not do much difference.

Comment: Thank you Maroun Maroun, i think first time not to use math libraries) Sure  it is comfortable)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new double variable and assign sc.nextDouble() to that double variable.

Example: 
double checkDouble;
....

```
else if(sc.hasNextDouble()){
    checkDouble=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Nooo " + check + " NO it is not INT");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

While trying your code in Eclipse, there was en error using `check = sc.nextDouble()` (`check` being an `int`), you can fix it like that:

```
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Your number? ");
    final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
      final int check = sc.nextInt();
      System.out.println("OKEI " + check + " IT IS INTEGER! ");
    } else if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
      final double check = sc.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("Nooo " + check + " NO it is not INT");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Failed.");
    }
  }
```

That way, you won't lose any decimal part using `Math.floor` or a cast.

Comment: Thanks and your code same like Lwax answered. But i see constanta(final) please why we have to use it?

Comment: Because my Eclipse is configured to make all variable/parameter/member not being modified as final. As to why you would use it ? 
To forbids for changing the value (or reference for objects) - which I think is important in case of parameters/members, less in case of variable.

Answer (score 0):

Cast int to double value, It may help.

```
else if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
            check = (int) sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Nooo " + check + " NO it is not INT");
        }
```

Comment: i entered 1.25 and my message is (Nooo 1 NO it is not INT) so 1.25 converts to 1 ( I try to have the same== 1.25 ))